# How to set the monitor brightness gracefully at boot time?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, xorg, gnome, monitors

I've been using a loop that contains `xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.3` in a bash script which will automatically execute right after logging in by `gnome-session-properties` (a.k.a. Startup Applications).

Is there any configuration file that can control the monitor brightness while a display connects to the X server? In short, how to set the monitor brightness at boot time?

Comment: An up is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from [Ji m's Ubuntu handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/):

> Open your file browser and navigate to “Computer-> sys -> class ->
>   backlight” directory. You’ll see two or three folders there:
>
> [image]
>
> In each folder there’s a file called actual_brightness, you can see
>   its content (brightness value) through the thumbnail icon.
>
> [image]
>
> Remember them and do:
>
> Change your screen brightness through Fn + Arrow key.
>
> Check out the actual_brightness files in each folder (Re-open each
>   folder to refresh the value).
>
> Does the value change?
>
> Remember the folder name in which the value of actual_brightness
>   changes. Replace acpi_video0 in below commands with that folder name
>
> 1. Press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the command below will give you the maximum level of your laptop
>      backlight:
>
>    ```
>    cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
>    ```
>
>    Mine is 9, so I can set backlight level from 0 to 9.
> 2. Run the command below one by one. You’ll get the super user privilege and open the /etc/rc.local file, a script executed at the
>      end of each multiuser runlevel, with gedit editor.
>
>    ```
>    sudo -i
>    gedit /etc/rc.local
>    ```
>
>    Add the line below before the last. Change the number 0 to the
>      brightness level you want.
>
>    ```
>    echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
>    ```

Comment: [When you copy text from someone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), it isn't enough to add a discreet link to someone else who cited it (and did it right by reframing the content in his own words). You **must** indicate the source and you **must** clearly mark copied content as such.